# Angular popover UIBotstrap event before open popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a grid with a few rows and when clicking on each row Angular popover UIBotstrap is opened. My problem is that I want the popover to be filled with some data of the row (like row id) and some data that I take from the server, so I added `ng-click`, but the popover is called before that data is received and the popover data doesn't get filled with that data.

Code:

templateUrl: 'realTimeAdherence/popovers/unknownActivityStatusPopover.tpl.html'

```
<button class="buttonPopover" ng-click="onUnmappedEventBtnClicked(\'' + params.data.acdEventId + '\',\'' + params.data.acdEventReasonCode + '\')" popover-class="user-tooltip popoverBehindModal" uib-popover-template="unknownActivityStatusPopover.templateUrl" popover-trigger="focus" popover-append-to-body="true">' +
'<img class="status-image" asset-src="/img/user_management/ico_status_pending_alert.png"></button>
```

How can I open the popover dynamically only after the data is received?

Answer (score 0):

In some exceptional cases I used setTimeout() in my controller. It's kinda manual, but it has worked in most of my complex scenarios.